Files in submodule, which is a public github repository, is not visible in GitHub action
There is git submodule , dictionary-jpa, in a public github repository https://github.com/rxue/dictionary-ci-cd
The content of .gitmodules is the following
[submodule "dictionary-jpa"]
    path = dictionary-jpa
    url = git@github.com:rxue/dictionary-jpa.git

On base of this setup, a Github Action is created with the following script
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        submodules: true
        #settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file
    - name: List submodule content
      run: |
        ls -al dictionary-jpa
    - name: Build submodule
      run: mvn -B compile --file dictionary-jpa/pom.xml

This action is expected to compile the code inside the submodule dictionary-jpa
Problem: Based on the output of the command ls -al dictionary-jpa, the submodule is empty when the action is being executed, thus the mvn compile failed since it cannot find the pom.xml in the first event even though the original repository i.e. the submodule has all the needed files. There is a FATAL error in the Action log:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /home/runner/work/dictionary-ci-cd/dictionary-ci-cd/dictionary-jpa/pom.xml: /home/runner/work/dictionary-ci-cd/dictionary-ci-cd/dictionary-jpa/pom.xml (No such file or directory) @ 

I added the submodules: recursive according to answers from some other similar questions, but it does not work.

submodules: recursive should be under actions/checkout, not actions/setup-java. See https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage.

@Azeem thanks a lot :) if you answer in the reply, I will click it as right answer as I tested already :)

This question is similar to: How to checkout submodule in GitHub action?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@LexLi yes, but the question you linked contains lots of noises, which is not suitable for beginner to use as a learning reference. I, a beginner, indeed read answers from the question u linked, but did not get the critical part of solution for my problem

@LexLi Akeem's answer is simple but that answered exactly the problem of my code posed there
